# Cannot understand Apache Stanbol enhancer response (Semantic Web)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, apache-stanbol

I am new to semantic web and trying to understand. I am using `Apache Stanbol`
I am seding text to enhance using Restful service and getting a Structure like

```
ID:               enhancement-e7a7f095-d127-0b6f-16db-b89d181c8314
confidence:       0.9877373098687467
created:          2012-03-19T17:01:03.879Z
creator:          org.apache.stanbol.enhancer.engines.opennlp.impl.NEREngineCore
end:              1458
extracted-from:   content-item-sha1-18a53d775839d36bf1cc220b3a3fa813a6a64593
relation:         enhancement-92681e65-f8c8-fb90-aed2-de05f7898ab9
selected-text:    Cologne
start:            1451
type:             Place,TextAnnotation,Enhancement
```

What I wanted to ask is what does `start`, `end` means? and `relation` contains a comma seprated list of IDs. How may I access the related IDs using `SPARQL`

Comment: Really you are getting such a simple structure :D?

Answer (score 1):

- **start**: The start character position within the plain text version of the parsed content. Note that the plain text version can be
  retrieved by using the multi-part content item support of the Stanbol
  Enhancer RESTful API.
- **end**: The end character position. This MUST only be present of "fise:start" is also defined.
- **relation**: Specifies that the current fise:Enhancement has a relation to an other fise:Enhancement. Values need to be resources of the "rdf:type" "fise:Enhancement".

from [Apache Stanbol online documentation](http://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/components/enhancer/enhancementstructure.html).